# Будет ли Visual Studio запрещен в России?

Tags: c#

Все мы знаем, что Microsoft ушел с Российского рынка в связи с последней ситуацией. Я нигде не вижу новостей о том, что Visual Studio нельзя будет использовать в России в будущем. Хотелось бы узнать, запретят ли продолжать использовать Российским компания VS? Или это уже будет считаться пиратством? Значит ли это, что .NET разработчиков больше не будет в России? Какие есть аналоги VS (кроме среды JetBrains Rider, компания которой уходит с Российского рынка) для разработчиков?

Comment: Насчёт Visual Studio не знаю, но нет абсолютно никаких ограничений (ни технических, ни юридических), которые бы мешали использовать .NET и без Visual Studio

Comment: На всякий случай интернет не включайте )))